# Run the loop to the number of xml elements in SQLServer

Tags: sql-server, xml, foreach

I have an xml and I want an operation to be repeated in the query for each xml element.

Please help me

```
DECLARE @PersonelIds XML
    = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
       <ArrayOfPersonelsIdsVm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
           <PersonelsIdsVm>
               <PersonelId>c2aadd5d-209d-ec11-8f3c-b42e99ed152b</PersonelId>
           </PersonelsIdsVm>
           <PersonelsIdsVm>
               <PersonelId>0d197668-209d-ec11-8f3c-b42e99ed152b</PersonelId>
           </PersonelsIdsVm>
       </ArrayOfPersonelsIdsVm>';

DECLARE @FromDate DATE = CONVERT(DATE, '2022/05/1');
DECLARE @Days INT = 0;

--XML Initialize
DECLARE @handler INT;
EXEC sys.sp_xml_preparedocument @handler OUT, @PersonelIds;

DECLARE @i INT =0

WHILE 'xml count' <= @i
BEGIN
    -- 'my code ...  for example : print PersonelId'
END
```

Help me find the elements in order in the loop

Comment: Not really clear what you are trying to do here but I doubt you need a loop.

Comment: While asking a question, you need to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example):
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements. 
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL. 
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft proprietary `OPENXML()` and its companions `sp_xml_preparedocument` and `sp_xml_removedocument` are kept just for backward compatibility with the obsolete SQL Server 2000. Their use is diminished just to very few fringe cases.
Starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards, it is strongly recommended to re-write your SQL and switch it to XQuery.

Also, `OPENXML()` cannot take advantage of XML indexes while XQuery methods can.

**SQL**

```
DECLARE @PersonelIds XML =
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ArrayOfPersonelsIdsVm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
    <PersonelsIdsVm>
        <PersonelId>c2aadd5d-209d-ec11-8f3c-b42e99ed152b</PersonelId>
    </PersonelsIdsVm>
    <PersonelsIdsVm>
        <PersonelId>0d197668-209d-ec11-8f3c-b42e99ed152b</PersonelId>
    </PersonelsIdsVm>
</ArrayOfPersonelsIdsVm>';

SELECT c.value('(PersonelId/text())[1]', 'UNIQUEIDENTIFIER') AS PersonelId
FROM @PersonelIds.nodes('/ArrayOfPersonelsIdsVm/PersonelsIdsVm') AS t(c);
```

**Output**

```
+--------------------------------------+
|              PersonelId              |
+--------------------------------------+
| C2AADD5D-209D-EC11-8F3C-B42E99ED152B |
| 0D197668-209D-EC11-8F3C-B42E99ED152B |
+--------------------------------------+
```

Comment: Thank you , but it is not my answer

Comment: I added a comment under your original question. Check it out.